# TypeScript `string literal` subsets not assignable to full set in overloaded function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, union-types

## Problem

Trying to create a mapping function for typed key-value pairs:

```
type Color = {
  "Red": number,
  "Green": string
  "Yellow": boolean
  "Purple": object
};
type PropMapping = {
  "Apple": Pick<Color, "Red" | "Green">,
  "Banana": Pick<Color, "Yellow" | "Green">,
  "Grape": Pick<Color, "Purple" | "Green">
}

function map(key: "Apple"): Pick<Color, "Red" | "Green">;
function map(key: "Banana"): Pick<Color, "Yellow" | "Green">;
function map(key: "Grape"): Pick<Color, "Purple" | "Green">;
function map(key: keyof PropMapping): Partial<Color> {
  // perform actual mapping in here (e.g. via switch-case)
  return {};
}
```

Later on I try to use this mapping function, but with a subset of the `Color` type

```
// type of fruits is a subset of `keyof PropMapping`
const fruits: (keyof Pick<PropMapping, "Apple" | "Banana">)[] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Banana"];

// call the mapping function on each fruit
const colors: Partial<Color>[] = fruits.map(fruit => map(fruit));
```

However, on the call to `map(fruit)` I get the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"Apple" | "Banana"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Grape"'

Type '"Apple"' is not assignable to type '"Grape"'.
```

Seems odd to me since the `fruit` parameter is a subset of the possible fruits that could be passed in. Having trouble making this mapping function overload work **without using the `as` keyword** (needing `as` is a bit of code-smell to me).

## End Goal

I would like to be able to reconstruct `Color` from one or more `Partial<Color>`s. For instance, say I do this:

```
const redGreen = map("Apple");
const yellowGreen = map("Banana");
const purpleGreen = map("Grape");

const allColors: Color = {
  ...redGreen,
  ...yellowGreen,
  ...purpleGreen
};
```

The above works as TypeScript can infer that the aggregated `Color` object's properties are all there. However, I'd like to maintain the ability to also aggregate `Partial<Color>` objects as show in the example above:

```
const colors: Partial<Color>[] = fruits.map(fruit => map(fruit));
```

This is the part that breaks for me

### Edits

**EDIT:**
Changed `Color` to be an object to better model my situation (and make it easier for others to copy-paste into their own IDEs

**EDIT2:**
Fixing overload return types

**EDIT3:**
`(keyof Pick<PropMapping, "Apple" | "Banana">)[]`...oh gosh. Thanks everyone for pointing these out

Comment: `Pick<Color, "Apple" | "Banana">` is not valid since `Pick` selects properties but `Color`, a subtype of `string`, has no `"Apple"` or `"Banana"` properties.  Please consider modifying the above code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE so others can demonstrate the issue for themselves. Good luck!

Comment: oops. true true. Was trying to model my actual use-case without straight up showing the code. Will modify

Comment: Note that `Pick<Color, "Apple" | "Banana">` is still not valid because `Color`'s properties are different 

Comment: @buuchan Do you mean `const fruits: (keyof Pick<PropMapping, "Apple" | "Banana">)[]`?

Comment: @AlexWayne yes yes. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript does not support calling multiple overload signatures at the same time.  It is conceivable that the compiler could support resolving such calls by allowing unions of the arguments and then returning a union of the return types, but this is not a feature, at least for now.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) for an open suggestion for this sort of support.

Unless and until this is supported, you'll need to refactor your code if you want the compiler to understand this sort of call.   You *could* add a call signature for each possible expected set of parameters, but that's only feasible for a small number of initial overload sets, since if you start with *n* disjoint call signatures you'd end up with 2<sup>*n*</sup> merged signatures.

---

For the particular example code you've posted where you are mapping keys to value types, by far the most straightforward solution is to abandon overloads (or at least abandon multiple call signatures) in favor of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function, like this:

```
function map2<K extends keyof PropMapping>(key: K): PropMapping[K];
function map2(key: keyof PropMapping): Color {
    return null!;
}
```

Here, `map2` takes a `key` parameter of generic type `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be a key of your `PropMapping` type, and it returns `PropMapping[K]`, the type of the value you get when you [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `K` key in a `PropMapping` object.

Then your array call should work:

```
const colors = fruits.map(fruit => map2(fruit));
// const colors: (Pick<Color, "Red" | "Green"> | Pick<Color, "Green" | "Yellow">)[]
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigbwLACgpQBEAShACaEBcUAdgK4C2ARhMgDR4GEDiyEENKlADOwZAEsaAcyiciATQgIkAdyFM4iCAEMacwgAU6yMAghC4TAFYQAxsDwBfANx5QkKAeRwwAWW1gYJIyGDj4RACCgWZCBuK2ANYAPPBI7ESkFFAAPkS8-IIAfBzhhABCupWx8cmpKGwKSqqEOXl8AoTF+rwB5tRxiSmI9URGJjGtPO1FTnh4AGZ0NPbicDRQDAEAFAkQINSEUabmAJT9NUNpDSTkLblTBZ2uuIvLwKvrm2A7ewcVNFUzp4LnV0oRFMo4GpJvkOoVnq8VmsNttdvs2r1CECBrVhmCxsc7m1HvCFkskZ9Ub8oGi4PNPN4-AEgtJsdpkO9tAhLihClg5AB6AVQSDIeYoBhQbT2OhclGBYJQSRQAAWrGgWwgADopFqoAA3cTaEQqcTAWwqgC0tm0wggJzkfGAxnWmBcsxe5PeyK+ACYkgBpKAQAAewAEZGENL2dIZPn8CukhR+6ID2MZCZZUgA2gGALoIr0feW+lPUWn0rzx5nBIGg-nhAhOl20OjKACEz0cc1wQqg7mgsfmyDoZqj4ijxuEdCYduAUFjAAMK3GmYmpIu8LY1qIoMPR8BhNQtodouZJv9Adm8+goNnT4TrpeAYQn5UXwWe32bcp+2r5Vme5FsiyI6Bae4jmaW47vO25pFGGD7mOWpfFsSHzmgfJ+mhkHACcJzPN+MFQHBKBHlAWw4jyYKZESDxwq0VGgtcsKCJMELNIUJzXkAA)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, that GitHub thread looks essentially like what I'm asking for. However, I was able to get it to work by adding one extra (and kind of redundant) overload:

`function map(key: keyof PropMapping): Partial<Color>;`

right before the function implementation

Comment: Yes, if you're okay with `colors` being wider than necessary (e.g., in the above, `"Purple"` is not in the return type because you didn't pass in a `"Grape"`)

Comment: That's true. Reconstructing/inferring a partially aggregated `Pick<Color, T>` is limited (as you pointed out). Luckily I just need to distinguish between the "wider" `Partial<Color>` and the completed `Color` types.